# RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes call - iOS notifications

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications

I am building an iOS application using Xamarin that utilizes push notifications using the Apple Push Notification Server.

According to the Apple Documentation, you need to call the `UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes` to register your application for push notification.

Does this method always need to be called from the `FinishedLaunching` method in the `AppDelegate` class?  Can I call it from another method within the application while the application is running?

For example, I would like to create a switch within the application that initiates the registration process.  I got this pattern working within an Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be called from anywhere, it doesn't have to be in the app delegate or on app startup. The didRegisterForRemoteNotifications, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications and didReceiveRemoteNotification functions are always in the app delegate though.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to verify.